# .on('mouseover', d => ..) does not provide same `d` as .attr('foo', d => ..)

Tags: typescript, d3.js, grafana

I have a mouseover tooltip working in Observable that fails when I port it to a Grafana plugin (React + D3 with Typescript).

I followed the technique in this article:
https://observablehq.com/@d3/learn-d3-interaction?collection=@d3/learn-d3

I have reduced the code to the following simplest form with lots of console.log's:

```
      const mouseGroup = chart
        .append('g')
        .attr('fill', 'none')
        .attr('pointer-events', 'all');
      const foobar = mouseGroup
        .selectAll('rect')
        .data<[number, number]>(plainArray)
        .join('rect')
        .attr('x', d => {
          console.log('d in x', d);
          console.log('xScale', xScale(d[0]));
          return xScale(d[0]);
        })
        .attr('y', d => yScale(d[1]))
        .attr('height', height)
        .attr('width', '5') // Hard-coded during debugging.
        .on('mouseover', (d, i) => {
          console.log(d, i);
          console.log(plainArray);
          tooltip.show(d);
        })
        .on('mouseout', () => tooltip.hide());
```

When I mouse-hover over a rect, I expect to see a console log of `d` datum like `[123, 456]`, but instead I see just a small integer. The first rect, index `0`, has `d` of `4`, which is unexpected. Please ignore the type errors because the problem is the `console.log(d, i)`:

[image]

So, next I console log `.attr('x', d => ...` and I see the expected `d` datum:

[image]

I don't understand why .attr() is provided with the expected `d` but .on() has a completely different `d` (and just a simple int).

Here are the other values of `d` in `.on('mouseover', (d, i) => {` (the values never change):

```
i=0, d=4
i=1, d=8
i=2, d=15
i=3, d=16
i=4, d=23
i=5, d=42
```

Again, it works as expected in Observable. I'm embedding this into a Grafana plugin. Could Grafana be messing with the mouseover and `d`?

As a test, I added mouseover code to change the rect fill color to "yellow", and that worked OK.
So I know my mouseover function is being executed. And from the beginning, the console.log's fire when I hover over each rect.

Another weird thing: `plainArray` has 312 elements, but I see only the first six elements when I inspect the DOM. However I do see hundreds of console.log's created by `.attr('x', ...)`

`plainArray` is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

omg, :facepalm:

When I typed `but I see only the first six elements when I inspect the DOM`, I realized these elements must be altered by other parts of my code.
Sure enough, I found code at the bottom that also selected `rect` elements.

```
const values = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];
...
         const bars = chart
           .selectAll('rect')
           .data(values)
...
```

After I removed the code that was also selecting `rect`, everything worked as expected.

*Always delete your old code.*